# How to construct a regex which is not preceded by a specific character?

Tags: c++, regex, pcre

I'm preparing a PCRE regex in c++.
I want to prepare a regex in which it should not be preceded by specific character.

Suppose I have following input strings:

```
Str1 = "www.host.com/abc/files/my.pdf" 
Str2 = "www.host.com/abc/files/takeprint.jsp?filenam=my.pdf"
```

How the regex will look like that matches with Str1 but not with Str2.

I tried following regex, but it din't worked.

```
regex = "(.+)my(.*)(?<!\?)pdf$"
```

Comment: Do you want it to fail if preceded by `=`?

Comment: yes, if "?" character is present before "pdf$", it should fail.

Answer (score 0):

Use a negative lookahead at the start.

```
^(?!.*\?.*\.pdf$).+my\.pdf$
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/nU9oF1/1)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a RegEx that I think solves the problem:

```
.*/([^?]+?\.pdf$)
```

It will greedily match anything up to the last `/`. After this it will capture a string of any length that does not contain a `?`, as long as the end of the string ends in `.pdf`.

The important part is the character set `[^?]` which covers any character that isn't a question mark.